How to Style certain words in ExternalLanguage cells?
I know I can Style all content of a cell using:
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions->Notebook[{
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
        Cell[
            StyleData["ExternalLanguage"],
            FontWeight->Bold,
            FontColor->Blue
        ]
    }]
]

But how do I target specific words in the content?
For example if the words select,from and where appears then apply the Style[#,FontWeight->Bold,FontColor->Blue]&.
There must be a way to do this, either through documented or undocumented functions.

There is AutoStyleWords (read John Fultz's answer), but it doesn't seem to work in the ExternalLanguage cell (probably because it isn't a "typeset cell"?).

Not exactly for this as these are not evaluatable (AFAIK) but there is a SyntaxHighlight resource function that you might find useful. It requires Python and kind of works sometimes but it is in need of further development. I have sent feedback but it is still a 1.0 version...

@GustavoDelfino it does on the content but also lacks customizability like choosing your own colors. But most importantly how do you connect it to the ExternalLanguage cell so it works automatically in the background?

@user13892 I would be happy if it did the just the content styling part well. It is wrapper around the popular pygments python library. This library is mature but the wrapper is not. But hey, it is open source. Last time I used it I had to fix some stuff to make it work for the language I was interested in.

I tried before using wolfram's own styling function because it is slow. And I don't think it is suitable for live syntax highlighting for ExternalLanguage cell. It takes couple of seconds for each call. Regardless I need a way to connect the styling function to ExternalLanguage cell. That is the main problem.

@Domen AutoStyleWords only works for wolfram language words and not arbitrary words.
